# Better way to do this SQL by using YII CDbCriteria or find() methods?

Tags: php, yii

I have a simple `SQL` query that I want to run via [Yii 1.15 ORM](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/).

**SQL Syntax**

```
SELECT ( sum(last_question) - count(last_question) ) as data 
FROM tbl_game 
WHERE last_question <> 0
```

**My questions are**

1. What would be better Yii way to do it?
2. Also is it possible to get return in integer value rather than [CModel Object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel) if using Yii?

**Update 1 :**

I have already tried something like this. It never return `question_answered`.I don't know why its doing that. If `CDbCriteria` has such option as `select` then it should work.

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select    = '( sum(`last_question`) - count(`last_question`) ) as "question_answered" ';
    $criteria->condition = "last_question <> 0";
    return game::model()->find($criteria);
```

**Update 2 :**

This is the raw output of the above criteria returned model. There is no `question_answered`in this.

I am sure there are records in table.

Also I have replaced the **" with '** as suggested. It still doesn't give `question_answered`

```
object(game)[103]
public 'points' => null
private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
private '_related' (CActiveRecord) => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
private '_c' (CActiveRecord) => null
private '_pk' (CActiveRecord) => null
private '_alias' (CActiveRecord) => string 't' (length=1)
private '_errors' (CModel) => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
private '_validators' (CModel) => null
private '_scenario' (CModel) => string 'update' (length=6)
private '_e' (CComponent) => null
private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

Comment: It will never give you some 'question_answered'. You are doing a `Model->find()` which will always return an active record or null. You cannot fill a complex select into this and get a model back, since Yii doesn't know how to map the result to a model. `Find` is more like a filter of records. What is it actually that you select here? What exactly do you want to receive?

Comment: `question_answered` from the very first SQL query. I get it its not possible to get int, I will get the CModel. But why I can't perform this thing with CDbCriteria

Comment: Because you get (and want?) an integer, but `Model->find()` will return an active record model or null. It doesn't make sense to do this with a find(). What is this integer? An ID of a model or just a count of something? If it doesn't relate to a model (like an ID) it just doesn't make sense to get this via find().

Comment: if you read the question, the `last_question` is base of my calculation. Its an integer value. this is what I want to return  `sum(last_question) - count(last_question)` using this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you.
The main problem you have is, that you want to select a field which does not exist in the model ('question_answered'). So the thing you need to do is add this field to the model.

The model:

```
class Game extends CActiveRecord {
  ...
    public $question_answered;
  ...
}
```

Then you can do sth like this:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = '(sum(`last_question`)-count(`last_question`)) as question_answered';
    $criteria->condition = "last_question <> 0";
    echo Game::model()->find($criteria)->question_answered;
```

Each time you add a non existing field in the `select` clause, you have to add this field in the model.

Hope this helps, it works for me.

Comment: how do you want to avoid it?

Comment: i will use some other existing property like `id` to get temp result in. Since it will be mostly scalar fetch query so it won't hurt :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Query Builder`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('SUM(`last_question`) - COUNT(`last_question`)') // if using "()", than you have to escape columns names manualy.
    ->from('tbl_game')
    ->where('last_question != :param', [':param' => 0])
    ->queryScalar();
```

With CDbCriteria, try something like this (not tested):

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->select = 'SUM(`last_question`) - COUNT(`last_question`) AS "result"';
$c->addCondition('last_question != :param');
$c->params = [':param' => 0];

Game::model()->find($c)->result;
```

Comment: is it possible to do it by find or CDbCriteria, My main focus is to select column using find method. is it possible?

Comment: yeah but I have already tried it. see updated question. It never return the "result"

Comment: @sushant Because you are returning full model, return only `return game::model()->find($criteria)->question_answered;`

Comment: object doesn't have any property named question_answered :(

Comment: In the model make class atrribute `public $result;` and use @Justinas code with CDbCriteria and it will work

Comment: didnt work it shows `object(game)[103]
  public 'points' => null
  public 'result' => null
  private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false`

Answer (score 0):

To get the value directly and not as a model you can use DAO/PDO:

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(`last_question`) - COUNT(`last_question`) AS data
FROM tbl_game
WHERE last_question <> :param';
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$value = $command->queryScalar(array(':param' => 0));
```

`$value` is then the first record found.
If you want multiple records you can do a `$values = $command->queryAll(true, array(':param' => 0))` which returns an array.

[More info here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao)

Comment: my point is to perform it using CDBcriteria or find methods. Is it possible?

Comment: I was refering to your 2nd question 'Get an int an not a model'. You can do it with CDbCriteria like you written above. Just take out the double quotes from your select. What is it that you get back? Some kind of ID? If so you will have to retrive the model with a `findByPk` also.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more neat option you could use, which *I am not sure if applies to your case*. If you have some model which relates to the model with **last_question** attribute and the relation is *HAS_MANY* or *MANY_MANY* you could define *STAT* relation in your first model and than call as any other relation.

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'someVariableName'=>array(self::STAT, 'ModelNameWhichYouRelateto', 'foreignkey_attr', array(
            'select'=>'SUM(last_question) - COUNT(last_question)',
            'condition'=>'last_question <> 0'
        )),
    );
}
```

You can then call it simply with

```
$model->someVariableName
```

and get an integer.

Comment: `last_question` is in the same table so I cant use relations